# what is the ''/home" after the website domain name?

Tags: web

I'm new to web development and i want to ask that why some website have the "/"?
for example https://www.roblox.com/home, notice the "/home" what does that called
I have tried to search on google and i can't find the answer 
And some website have like "/login.php", "/index.html" it can also be html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are URLs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) and they identify the resource you are trying to reach. I would suggest reading more about how web pages works to get a better general overview of things(e.g.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/How_the_Web_works)

How these resources are actually interpreted depends on the server side implementation:

- .php are usually processed by PHP web server
- Other static files such as images (*.png , *.jpg, etc), html files, svgs, CSS, js, etc - Are usually located in the local server by the web server (httpd, tomcat, IIS, nodejs, and many many others) and the files as transmitted to the client 'as-is'

When using online tools to build websites, these complexities are usually abstracted away, and in the end URLs will just mean a resource identifier.

Answer (score 0):

`[domain]/[section]/[page(.html|.php)|resource(.js|.css)]`

**domain:** the address of the website

**section:** a way to navigate inside the website itself

**page:** the user interface that might be rendered server side of client side hold the controls shown to user

**resource:** files that changes how the content in the pages looks and behaves like